# How can I determine what what is in the Win10 UAC prompt in Python?

Tags: python, windows, uac

Here's was appears to be an odd question at least from what I've been able to turn up in Google. I'm not trying to determine IF there's a UAC prompt (I've got a couple of reliably ways to do that, win32gui,GetForegroundWindow() returns a 0, or win32gui.screenshot returns exception OSError at least in my case)

I'm also not looking to BYPASS the UAC, at least from python, I have an update process that's kicking off automatically that I need to get through the UAC. I don't have control of the update process so I don't think it's a good candidate for disabling the UAC with Python. I could just disable the UAC in Win10, but I'd prefer not to if possible. I do have a couple of methods for bypassing the UAC, in one instance where I'm running this in vitualbox I believe I can use VBoxManage guestcontrol to sent keystrokes to the guest system, for a stand alone system I have a microcontroller connected as a USB HID Keyboard, with a basic deadman switch (using the scroll lock to pass data between the python and the microcontroller acting as the HID keyboard) if it doesn't get the signal it sends left arrow enter to bypass the UAC.

What I'm trying to do, and getting stymied with, is verifying that the UAC popup is actually from the update process that I want to accept the UAC prompt for, and not some other random, possibly nefarious application trying to elevate privileges. I can use the tasklist to verify the UAC is up, but I'm not seeing any way to see WHAT caused the UAC prompt. The update process is kicked off from an application that's always running, so I can't check to see if the process itself it running, because it's running under normal operation, I just want to accept the UAC when it's attempting to elevate privileges to update. I've been using a combination of using win32gui.GetWindowText and win32gui.EnumWindows to look for specific window titles, and for differentiating between windows with the same title, taking a screenshot and using OpenCV to match different object that appear in the windows. Both of those methods fail though when UAC is up, which is why I can use them to detect UAC as I mentioned before.

I suppose I could use a USB camera to take a screenshot of the system, but I'd like to be able to run this headless.

Anybody have an idea on a way to accomplish this, as the tree said to the lumberjack, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a process as administrator, no user account control prompt will appear.
You could manually run your process as administrator.
You need system privileges to interact with a user account control prompt.

Comment: A good idea, but the process goes through 3 steps before it launches the actual running process (a TOS window, an update check, and then the process) I can execute the launcher as Administrator, but the next step it launches appears to be downgraded back to non-admin (at least the update step still fires UAC) - also I'd love to give you an upvote for useful comment even though it doesn't work for this situation but I guess I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: I don't see why the number of steps has anything to do with it. By default, a process starts with the same privilege as its parent process. It doesn't matter how many processes get spawned - if a process is elevated, the processes it starts are also elevated (unless said process takes special pains to "un-elevate" a process it starts).

Comment: Not sure, I'm assuming either it's taking pains to un-elevate itself, or because the update process only runs occasionally, I'm doing some back-end trickery to force the update process to run, and maybe I'm messing up something with that. Supposedly they're pushing an update next week, so I can give it a shot without messing with it, and we'll see if that works.

Comment: It does look like my testing was messing with running as admin working, as the normal update process working. Thanks!